# AWS ECS fargate service task is not picking up the updated ECR image via Codepipeline Cloudformation provider

Tags: docker, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs, aws-codepipeline, aws-fargate

Here is how the codepipeline was setup
1.Source -> codecommit
2.Build -> Codebuild will build the docker image from codecommit and push to ECR registry
3.Deploy -> Codedeploy will deploy the new image via cloudformation provider (ActionMode: CREATE_UPDATE)

I am able to successfully push the updated docker images to ECR , however the ECS fargate service is not being updated with the new changes and i am not sure what is wrong with my configuration. I am providing the service definition and pipeline configuration for reference:

Cloudformation Service definition:

```
  Service:
    Type: AWS::ECS::Service
    Properties: 
      Cluster: !Ref Cluster
      TaskDefinition: !Ref TaskDefinition
      LaunchType: FARGATE
      DeploymentConfiguration:
        **MaximumPercent: 200**
        **MinimumHealthyPercent: 0**
      DeploymentController:
        **Type: ECS**
      **DesiredCount: 1**
      HealthCheckGracePeriodSeconds: 120
      NetworkConfiguration: 
        AwsvpcConfiguration:
          AssignPublicIp: DISABLED
          Subnets:
            - !Ref PrivateSubnetOne
            - !Ref PrivateSubnetTwo
          SecurityGroups: 
            - !Ref ContainerSecurityGroup      
      LoadBalancers:
        - ContainerName: !Ref ServiceName
          ContainerPort: 80
          TargetGroupArn: !Ref TargetGroup
```

CodePipeline stage:

```
                  Name: Deploywebservice
                  ActionTypeId:
                    Category: Deploy
                    Owner: AWS
                    Version: "1"
                    Provider: CloudFormation
                  InputArtifacts:
                    - Name: Sourcefiles
                  Configuration:  
                    **ActionMode: CREATE_UPDATE**
                    StackName: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-webservice
                    RoleArn: !GetAtt CloudFormationRole.Arn
                    TemplatePath: SourceZip::web-service.yml
                    TemplateConfiguration: SourceZip::web-service-parameters.json 
                    Capabilities: CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM,CAPABILITY_AUTO_EXPAND
                  RunOrder: 1
```

I am really running out of ideas and hence posting it here for help.

Comment: `AssignPublicIp: DISABLED` if you disable public ip, how did you ensure that the farget has access to the internet to download the ECR image? Through VPC interface endpoints or nat gateway?

Comment: Because the private subnet has connectivity to NAT gateway , so i belive it can connect to internet to fetch the ECR image.

Comment: That should work. If you go to ECS console and serivce. Have you inspected the Events tab or info about stopped tasks? Usually there should be some info on what's happening.

Comment: I am not seeing any news updates in the events. If i increase the desired count in the cloudformation and commit it to codecommit then i see the changes being picked up, however what i want to achieve is the rolling update where by every time i push a change the ECS task definition should pull the ECR image and get updated. Not sure how to achieve this.

Comment: If you want ECS rolling deployment, why don't you use `Amazon ECS` provider in `Deploy` action of your CP?

Comment: I want to to try using cloudformation.